# Why is this logical expression using $P$, $Q$, $R$ logically equivalent to one using only $P$ and $Q$?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

Formula 1:

$$(¬P ∧ ¬Q ∧ ¬R) ∨ (¬P ∧ ¬Q ∧ R) ∨ (P ∧ Q ∧ ¬R) ∨ (P ∧ Q ∧ R)$$

```
P   Q   R   F
0   0   0   1
0   0   1   1
0   1   0   0
0   1   1   0
1   0   0   0
1   0   1   0
1   1   0   1
1   1   1   1
```

Formula 2:
$$(¬P ∧ ¬Q) ∨ (P ∧ Q)$$

```
P   Q   ((¬P ∧ ¬Q) ∨ (P ∧ Q))
0   0              1
0   1              0
1   0              0
1   1              1
```

How are these two formulas logically equivalent? To my understanding when two formulas are logically equivalent, they have identical truth values under all interpretations, these 2 formulas produce completely different truth tables- formula 1 has 3 variables and formula 2 has 2 variables to start off with. I don't understand how they are logically equivalent?

Comment: "*how they are logically equivalent*" $\;-\;$ The same way $\,R \lor \lnot R\,$ is logically equivalent to true, for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let the $3$-input function $F_1(P,Q,R)$ denote Formula 1's truth value, and likewise for Formula 2.

- The key insight is that in Formula 1, $R$ is a ‘bogus’
  (propositional) variable: whatever $P$ and $Q$'s values are,
  $F_1(P,Q,0)$ and $F_1(P,Q,1)$ are either both true or both false. So,
  the input combination $(P,Q)$ fully determines the Formula 1's truth
  value. To determine whether Formula 1 is true, there is never a need
  to consider input $R$'s truth value. $$F_1(P,Q,R)=F_1(P,Q).$$
- And, since each choice of $(P,Q)$ returns the same truth value for
  Formulae 1 and 2, these two formulae must therefore be logically
  equivalent. $$F_2(P,Q)=F_1(P,Q)=F_1(P,Q,R).$$ In fact, Formula 2 is a
  simplified version of Formula 1.

Comment: so to know that the two formulas are logically equivalent you must already know that R is a 'bogus' variable in formula 1 otherwise you wouldn't know they are logically equivalent right

Comment: @stevenoakman Logical equivalence of two formulae means that they have the same truth value regardless of interpretation and variable input. In propositional logic, this means that their truth tables *essentially* match. When there is a different number of input variables (three versus two in your exercise), this happens only if the 'extra' input variables are all 'redundant'; we can check this by studying the two formulae's truth tables, as we have above.

Answer (score 3):

Actually, they both have the same truth table. They only look different because you omitted $R$ from the second one, presumably due to the fact that it does not appear in the second formula. If we include $R$ in the second truth table, it becomes

```
P   Q   R   ((¬P ∧ ¬Q) ∨ (P ∧ Q))
0   0   0              1
0   0   1              1
0   1   0              0
0   1   1              0
1   0   0              0
1   0   1              0
1   1   0              1
1   1   1              1
```

As you can see, this is the same as the first one.

Comment: okay but R isn't included in the formula, how would I know in an exam that the two formulas are logically equivalent?

Comment: @stevenoakman $R$ does not explicitly appear in the formula, which is why its truth value does not depend on $R$. If it bothers you that we include $R$ in the truth table, you could consider appending $\wedge(R\vee\neg R)$ to the end of the formula, which would not change its truth value.

Answer (score 1):

Notice from your first truth table that the value of $F$ does not depend on $R$.  For each of the four possibilities for $(P,Q)$, the two formulas yield the same truth values.

Alternatively, you can show the equivalence directly without truth tables by manipulating the first formula to look like the second one:
$$
(¬P ∧ ¬Q ∧ ¬R) ∨ (¬P ∧ ¬Q ∧ R) ∨ (P ∧ Q ∧ ¬R) ∨ (P ∧ Q ∧ R) \\
((¬P ∧ ¬Q) ∧ ¬R) ∨ ((¬P ∧ ¬Q) ∧ R) ∨ ((P ∧ Q) ∧ ¬R) ∨ ((P ∧ Q) ∧ R) \\
((¬P ∧ ¬Q) ∧ (¬R ∨ R)) ∨ ((P ∧ Q) ∧ (¬R ∨ R)) \\
((¬P ∧ ¬Q) ∧ 1) ∨ ((P ∧ Q) ∧ 1) \\
(¬P ∧ ¬Q) ∨ (P ∧ Q) \\
$$

Comment: so for two formulas to be logically equivalent, they don't need to have the same number of variables? just that the truth values produced from one formula has to be the same in the other formula with more variables, in this case P and Q?

Comment: and how do you know the value of F doesn't depend on R?

Comment: By looking at each pair of consecutive rows in the truth table.  Changing only $R$ while keeping $P$ and $Q$ fixed does not affect the value of $F$.